# How to acces files without servlet in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

I want to access file (for example from `http://localhost:8080/myweb/styles.css`), but i dont want to write servlet for each static file on my web. Is there any way how to access that file without servlet?  I am using tomcat 7.

Comment: if the file is not below WEB-INF you should be able to access it from a browser.

Comment: Eh? The default servlet should automatically be serving static content. Unless you've really messed up the config. What happens when you visit your link?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/myweb/styles.css use this in browser it will work.

Comment: I was putting files into wtpwebapps instead of webapps (I am using eclipse)... Now it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to write servlet for this. All files located in root of your web application are accessible via HTTP.

For example if your web application has only one file `styles.css`, i.e. you have folder `myweb` that contains this file under `$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps` it is accessible automatically.

Comment: The definition of the default servlet (serving static resouces) can be found in tomcat_home/conf/web.xml.